# Sylius add admin Page

Tags: php, symfony, sylius

I'm trying to create an extra admin page in Sylius. However, the documentation does not explain how to create a new admin page. The page I want to create is a subcategory page.

I did manage to create a new route and to create a new controller, but the template uses a lot of functions that are not included in my custom Controller.

Do I need to extend my custom controller with `CreatePage` or something?

Answer (score 1):

If your page represents a CRUD operation on an entity, then [this page](https://docs.sylius.com/en/latest/cookbook/entities/custom-model.html) will help you do a basic setup.